# Value of id corresponding to max value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select 
    max(totalrentaltranscations) as MaxTranscations,
    firstsortedvalue(staff_id,totalrentaltranscations) as ID 
from Table
```

what is the name of the function that will give me the staff_id corresponding to max(totalrentaltranscations)

that is if MaxTranscation was 2000, what staff_id had MaxTranscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` + `limit`:

```
select 
    staff_id as id,
    totalrentaltranscations
from a_table
order by 2 desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! so no sorted value function here

Comment: In SQL you use `order by` to sort values. A function is just unnecessary here.